# Session configurada no Web.Config e na Session State do IIS está expirando antes do tempo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, iis

Cenário:

Eu armazeno a `Session` do usuário para manter ele logado no sistema, porém está acontecendo algo que em 10 minutos ele é deslogado porque a `Session` expirou.

Mas tanto no `Web.Config` quanto na **Session State** está parametrizada para 120 minutos e mesmo assim ela expira.

Exista algum processo do **IIS** que limpe as `Session`, independente desses parâmetros ?

Comment: vc colocou desse jeito <sessionState timeout="120"></sessionState> ?

Comment: O `IIS` tem uma configuração para reciclar o *Application Pool* em um determinado intervalo de tempo, já verificou lá, nas propriedades do AppPool como estão as configurações?

Comment: @RicardoPontual seria 'Disable Recycling for Configuration Changes' ?

Comment: Está nas configurações do AppPool, em "recycling", tem um campo em "Regular time interval (minutes)" onde você define o tempo. Zero significa que nunca recicla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

120 minutos no config vai ficar assim:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="120"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: *"algum dispose"* como assim? Dispose do que?

Comment: @RicardoPontual removi, dispose nao se aplica nesse caso.

Comment: Sim é isso que pensei, o objeto `Session` não implementa o `IDisposable`, por isso pode confundir ;)

Comment: Sim, a web.config está parametrizada desta forma, mas por algum motivo algum processo está limpando as Session, fazendo de forma que esse parametro fique obsoleto...

Comment: @IgorCarreiro ja tentou deletar o site no iis e da outro build?

Comment: ou vc pode olhar no session state o mode que esta sendo usado para o timeout